# Creating horizontal scrollview with dynamic data from API

Tags: api, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have a horizontal scroll view with multiple views inside it, the data inside views are retrieved from an API call so i don't know how many views I'm going to have inside the scroll view, is there a better way to implement this? and how can i can convert this to a flatlist if possible?

```
state = { data: [] };

async componentDidMount(){
      axios.get('http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts')
       .then((response) =>  { this.setState({ data: response.data})});
    }

<ScrollView horizontal={true} style={{width: '100%'}}>
  <View>
    <Text>
      {this.state.data.title}
    </Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right a FlatList would be a better solution for a dynamic data.

Here is a brief example based on the data that you are using.

```
class MyFlatList extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data:[] };
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('http://reduxblog.herokuapp.com/api/posts')
     .then((response) =>  { this.setState({ data: response.data})});
  }

  _keyExtractor (item, index) {
    return index.toString();
  }

   _renderItem ({ item, index }) {
    return (<Text>{item.title} - {item.categories}</Text>);
  }

  render() {
    return(
     <FlatList style={{ flex: 1 }}
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor.bind(this)}
        renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)}
        horizontal={true}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see the FlatList requires several props to be passed to it. Three of them are always required: keyExtractor, renderItem, and data

First the `keyExtractor`

> Used to extract a unique key for a given item at the specified index.
>   Key is used for caching and as the react key to track item re-ordering

Second the `renderItem`. The current renderItem returns a very simple component, with a bit of time and styling something pretty cool could be constructed.

> Takes an item from data and renders it into the list.

The data should be passed to the FlatList via the data prop. You are storing your data in the components state so we can pass it as `this.state.data`. The FlatList will use that to construct the list.

Finally we need to pass true to the horizontal prop so that the FlatList will construct a horizontal list rather than a vertical list.

More information can be found in the docs for the [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist). I suggest you take a look there and see what you can come up with.

Finally make sure that you have imported FlatList, View and Text from react-native otherwise you will have a few errors to deal with. I would also look at your axios request as you don't seem to be catching any errors that function might through.